# USB Wi-Fi not working on Windows 10 after it has been working perfectly

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-10

I have a 4G LTE Wi-Fi USB stick (Huawei E3372, CE0197).

I always used it connect on a laptop running Windows 10. I gave everything (laptop + USB Wi-Fi) for a friend during three days, and he did something wrong that I can not guess, so now my USB Wi-Fi does not work any more (even if I can access Internet without it).

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### My USB Wi-Fi does not work any more

Please do the following:

1. Reinstall any drivers required for your USB Wi-Fi.

   You can skip this step if no special drivers are needed.
2. Delete the Wi-Fi Network Profile. See below for instructions.
3. Create a new Wi-Fi connection.

---

#### How do I delete a Wi-Fi Network Profile on Windows 10?

Option 1: To Delete a Wireless Network Profile in Settings app
>

> 1. Open the Settings app, click/tap on the Network & Internet icon.
> 2. Click/tap on Wi-Fi in the left pane, and click/tap on the Manage Wi-Fi settings button under Wi-Fi on the right side.
>
>    [image]
> 3. Click/tap on a listed wireless network (ex: Brink-Router2) that you want to delete.
>
>    [image]
> 4. Click/tap on Forget.
>
>    [image]
> 5. When finished, you can close the Settings app if you like.

Option 2: To Delete a Wireless Network Profile in Command Prompt

> 1. Open a command prompt.
> 2. In the command prompt, copy and paste the command below, and press Enter.
>
>    Note: This command will give you a list of all wireless network
>      profiles on each interface on your PC.
>
>    netsh wlan show profiles
>
>    [image]
> 3. Do step 4 or step 5 below for how you would like to delete the profile.
> 4. To Delete a Wireless Network Profile from All Interfaces on PC
>
>    In the command prompt, type the command below, press Enter, and go to
>      step 6 below.
>
>    ```
>    netsh wlan delete profile name="WirelessProfileName"
>    ```
>
>    For example, if I wanted to delete my listed Brink-Router2 2 (name)
>      wireless network profile, I would type the command below exactly.
>
>    ```
>    netsh wlan delete profile name="Brink-Router2 2"
>    ```
>
>    [image]
> 5. To Delete a Wireless Network Profile from a Specific Interface on PC
>
>    In the command prompt, type the command below, press Enter, and go to
>      step 6 below. (see screenshot below)
>
>    ```
>    netsh wlan delete profile name="WirelessProfileName" interface="InterfaceName"
>    ```
>
>    For example, if I wanted to delete my listed Brink-Router2 (name)
>      wireless network profile only from the Wi-Fi interface, I would type
>      the command below exactly.
>
>    ```
>    netsh wlan delete profile name="Brink-Router2" interface="Wi-Fi"
>    ```
>
>    [image]
> 6. When finished, you can close the command prompt if you like.

Source: *[Wireless Network Profile - Delete in Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3507-wireless-network-profile-delete-windows-10-a.html)*

Comment: Very nice job. Thank you very much for the precious help.

Comment: Thank you shawn, thi is a very nice answer. Do you still have the files which you uploaded to tenforms.com without their branding? (Just to make sure we are allowed to show this without violating some of their rules.)

Comment: @hennes Shawn is not the person who answer (I am). I can't find any copywrite information on http://tenforms.com apart from a link to http://www.designermedia.com/ (which doesnt have any information apart from links to their network of sites). I have removed the images in the meantime.

Comment: @hennes. I don't have access to Window 10 to make screenshots :/

Comment: I also looked hoping that they explicitly allow reusage (just as SE does). I also failed to find it.  based on usage of answers from sevenforums etc I suspect it is not a problem, but it would be great if tenforums explicitly stated this (just as SE does).

Comment: @Hennes If we do get some confirmation that it is allowed I will be happy to rollback my edit - at the moment I feel it is better to play safe ... ;)

Comment: I routinely used those forums for some of my answers, I have also in the past included their screenshots, and uploaded them to the i.stack.imgur, and always provided a link back to the site.  I don't feel its a problem, as long as something is properly cited, they would have a hard time making any sort of claims.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. I will rollback to include the images.